# How to display a newly randomly generated quote from a specific API when clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Problem- I have an API that displays a random quote once the page loads. My button(div) called "newQuote" doesn't generate a new quote, instead, it displays the exact same quote, making my button useless.**

[My code can be found on GitHub here](https://github.com/ronlaniado/Random-Quote-Generator)
SO- 
I have a javascript function, called getNewQuote() that runs when my page loads. This function grabs a quote and author from an API (https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1), and appends it to my div with the class quoteTitle and quoteDisplay.

```
function getNewQuote() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1',
    jsonp: 'jsonp',
    cache: 'false',
    success: function(data) {
      var post = data.shift();
      $("#quoteTitle").empty();
      $("#quoteDisplay").empty();
      $("#quoteTitle").append(post.title);
      $("#quoteDisplay").append(post.content);
    }
  });
}

getNewQuote();
```

Then, I set another div called newQuote which, when clicked, would display a new quote.

```
$('#newQuote').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  getNewQuote();
```

Now, to me, it seems that the problem is caching. The reason that I think it is a cache problem is because if I go to the site on my phone using the app Firefox Focus, which (pretty sure) doesn't store any cache, the site will run as wanted, and will change my quote whenever I click on my #newQuote. You can try it for yourself at 'rqg.ronlaniado.me', where it is hosted.

Since my problem is cache, I did use some methods and plans to avoid this.

```
    cache: 'false',
```

I set cache-ing to false in my .ajax request.

```
  <script src="qg_js.js?v=42"></script>
```

I put "?v-42 which, according to Google, shouldn't keep cache stored.

If anyone can look through my code and assist me in solving my issue, that'd be great. Also, this is my first time posting here, so sorry if I am a bit messy with everything.

Comment: Remove `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Adding `?v-42` to the end of the URL just signifies that it's version 42. Once visited, it will begin to cache that. You'll either need to use a different version (such as 43), or use the current **time** as a version number, which will always be different :)

Comment: Your code is actually working...

Comment: @ChavaG I'm able to get a new quote every time my page is refreshed, but the problem is that clicking "New Quote" just returns the same quote that is already on my page, instead of a newly generated quote.

Comment: I'm actually getting a new quote displayed every time I click the "New Quote" button here- http://rqg.ronlaniado.me/

Comment: `cache: false`, not `cache: 'false'` (although `cache: false` should already be the default for jsonp requests). Your `?v-42` parameter (subject to what was already mentioned about that value needing to be unique to each call) would need to be on your *Ajax* URL, not your *script* URL.

Comment: @nnnnnn Wow! That worked! It's great now! P.S.- When I click everything is fine, but my cursor remains the same. Do you happen to know if it's possible to change the way my cursor looks when it's hovered over?

Comment: You can set the cursor via css: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was here:

```
cache: 'false';
```

The correct usage is:

```
cache: false;
```

These quotes caused cache to be kept, meaning that the quotes didn't change.